# how to properly accomodate a matrix in order to convert it to a positive semi-definite matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to convert a matrix to a semi-definite matrix by using `nearPSD()` function:

```
import numpy as np


phi_zero, phi_one= 0.7, -0.2

A=[[phi_zero, phi_one],
  [1, 0]]


def nearPSD(A,epsilon=0):
   n = A.shape[0]
   eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(A)
   val = np.matrix(np.maximum(eigval,epsilon))
   vec = np.matrix(eigvec)
   T = 1/(np.multiply(vec,vec) * val.T)
   T = np.matrix(np.sqrt(np.diag(np.array(T).reshape((n)) )))
   B = T * vec * np.diag(np.array(np.sqrt(val)).reshape((n)))
   out = B*B.T
   return out
```

However, when applied:

```
nearPSD(A=A)
```

The next error arises:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

How could I accomodate primitive `A` matrix in order to get a semi-definite matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `list` to a function that expects a `np.array`. Simple fix:

```py
nearPSD(A=np.array(A))
```